# Ubuntu gets corrupted after installing it in Desktop

Tags: boot, command-line, 22.04, fsck, busybox

I have been using ubuntu desktop version for more than six years now. However, recently (for about nine months) I’m facing an issue. The explanation of the issue is below,

Nine months ago, ubuntu os from my desktop got corrupted automatically, I don’t know why and how. Then, when I booted into ubuntu it showed me busy box error, for which I took help from ubuntu help community posts to get rid of it. Though it did remove the busy box error, but after some days when I restarted the system again I got the same error and now it showed me a blank screen. I did search for solutions to get rid of it but couldn’t find any. Hence, I had to reinstall it again by downloading a different version of ubuntu from the website, but alas! After some time the same error popped up  which is “/dev/sda2 has broken files, run fsck manually “. I searched for solutions and applied but it lasted for some days, and then again it got corrupted and showed me a blank screen. .

This is happening to me for last nine months and I’m formatting and reinstalling a new/different version of ubuntu everytime. It’s been more than 30 times I have done this and still every time the error occurs and ubuntu os gets corrupted. I also, checked whether it is a hardware issue or not. I performed tests regarding ROM/RAM/processor/ motherboard. Etc, but there aren’t any hardware related issue found. Please help me get rid of the error, I am not able to use my system, and I need ubuntu for my work/research. Please help.

Comment: Although you say it isn't a hardware issue, this sounds like a hard drive that's failing ...

Comment: Look at S.M.A.R.T. data of the disk `/dev/sda`. You can use the command `/usr/sbin/gsmartcontrol`.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. SMART will start screaming long after the hard disk fails.You can do the check though, like @FedKad suggested. I would change the hard disk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What tools do I have available to test a hard drive's health?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314181/what-tools-do-i-have-available-to-test-a-hard-drives-health)