# Filesystem error while booting

Tags: filesystem, fsck

I know there are some other posts similar to this one. But since I am a beginner, i would love to hear opinions specifically to my questions. When i boot, it fails with the following error:
[image]

I understand, that a manual filesystem check is needed here. But on some devices, even after i did the fsck, the error continuious to exist. Can anyone please explain me this behaviour ?

Comment: If fsck doesn’t resolve the issue one possibility is that the device is failing. I suggest you research how to check drive health. Here is one accepted answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/314181/what-tools-do-i-have-available-to-test-a-hard-drives-health You should be able to run tests from your system booted into a live environment e.g. the Ubuntu installation media choosing “Try Ubuntu “

Answer (score 0):

Do a backup of the partiton(s) of that disk and buy a new disk as soon as possible.
/dev/sda is at its end of life.